# Emboss Cons for getting consensus sequence for many files, not just one

Tags: perl, bioinformatics, fasta, consensus, emboss

I installed and configured emboss and can run the simple command line arguments for getting the consensus of one previously aligned multifasta file:

% **cons**

Create a consensus sequence from a multiple alignment

Input (aligned) sequence set: **dna.msf**

output sequence [dna.fasta]: **aligned.cons**

This is perfect for dealing with one file at a time, but I have hundreds to process. 
I have started to write a perl script with a foreach loop to try and process this for every file, but I guess I need to be outside of the script to run these commands. Any clue on how I can run a command line friendly program for getting a single consensus sequence in fasta format from a previously aligned multifasta file, for many files in succession? I don't have to use emboss- I could use another program. 
Here is my code so far:

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl 
   use warnings; 
   use strict; 

   my $dir = ("/Users/roblogan/Documents/Clustered_Barcodes_Aligned");

    my @ArrayofFiles = glob "$dir/*"; #put all files in the directory into an array

    #print join("\n", @ArrayofFiles), "\n";  #diagnostic print

    foreach my $file (@ArrayofFiles){
            print 'cons', "\n";
            print "/Users/roblogan/Documents/Clustered_Barcodes_Aligned/Clustered_Barcode_Number_*.*.Sequences.txt.out", "\n";
            print "*.*.Consensus.txt", "\n"; 
    }
```

Comment: Your `print` statements -- is that how a command looks? In other words, what exactly is the command you run by hand for just one pop?

Comment: can you please tell which EMBOSS tool you want to use ?

Comment: Hi Arijit- I am using EMBOSS CONS, as in the title of the question. Hi zdim, The exact commands that I run by hand successfully are: 1) cons 2) name the aligned file input 3) name the consensus file output, as in the example given in the question (in bold). The names can change, the prompt "cons" can't. The files I want to put into the workflow vary by numbers, indicated in my print statement by *.

Comment: Oh, I see -- this is an interactive tool. You start it and then enter things at its prompt. Sorry I missed that, thank you. That's a bit different. Does that tool have a 'batch' mode of some kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EMBOSS cons has two mandatory qualifier:

1. **- sequence**( to provide the input sequence)
2. **- outseq** (for output).

so you need to provide the above to field .

Now change your code little bit to run multiple program:

```
my $count=1;
foreach my $file (@ArrayofFiles){
            $output_path= "/Users/roblogan/Documents/Clustered_Barcodes_Aligned/";
            my $output_file = $output_path. "out$count";# please change here to get your desired output filename 
            my $command = "cons -sequence '$file' -outseq '$output_file' "; 
            system($command);
            $count ++;
}
```

Hope the above code will work for you.